# Angularjs - Several ng-repeat in the same table for different columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 arrays that I want to fill a table with. I want these values in different columns meaning :

```
Column1(People)|     Column2(Animals)|     Column3(Letters)|

        -----  |              -----  |              -----  |
        -----  |              -----  |              -----  |
        -----  |              -----  |              -----  |
        -----  |              -----  |              -----  |
```

Well I could make 3 tables and put them side by side but I wanted to know if I can make it like this.

As you can see, the result of the fiddle is ugly.

http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/243/

Comment: change your data structure so you have one array and each object has all the properties (columns) you want to display

Comment: Are the 3 sets of column data related? If not, use different tables, if yes, then do what @Daniel_L said.

Comment: This is @Daniel_L suggestion. http://jsfiddle.net/pf4kksg8/

Answer (score 1):

If you're really have no choice to handle your data in different arrays you can use **$index** to achieve that. (*never tested when the arrays having different length*) :

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{ people[$index].first + ' ' + people[$index].last }}</td>
        <td>{{ animals[$index].first + ' ' + animals[$index].last }}</td>
        <td>{{ letters[$index].first + ' ' + letters[$index].last }}</td>
    </tr>
```

[jsfiddle.net/9fR23/246](http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/246)

Or you can get the bigger array length like the follow:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in getMaxLength()">...
```

And somewhere in your controller:

```
$scope.getMaxLength = function() {
//....
return max;
}
```

Elsewhere you can handle them in the same Array as @Daniel suggested. It depends how your data is..

Comment: I changed my data structure. I made an array with multiple fields and push the items of the 3 arrays in it, looping with the max length of the 3 arrays